# sch-i905 shuts off

Tags: applications

Sch-i905 shuts off when I try to use camera and other apps. I have to plug it back into the charger to turn it back on. Does it have a virus or could a app be causing the problem. The camera worked up until a few days ago.

Comment: Backup your data, and factory reset your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to backup all of your data and factory reset your phone. If that doesn't solve the problem, you should bring your phone back and ask for warranty.